# Constraint Layout memory leak on Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-viewbinding

So, i'am trying to learn about memory leaking with Leak Canary, and found that every fragment that i have is leaking. I'am using viewbinding in here, and here is the log:

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instance
    Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.lelestacia.lelenimexml.feature.anime.ui.home.
    AnimeFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks))
    Retaining 3.0 kB in 63 objects
    key = e41d026f-fe51-475c-bb6a-ddbb25fe0bd0
    watchDurationMillis = 13782
    retainedDurationMillis = 8781
    View not part of a window view hierarchy
    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    mContext instance of dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper, wrapping
    activity com.lelestacia.lelenimexml.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
```

Even when i tried to set the binding to null inside onDestroyView, the constraint layout of all fragment is still leaking.